# References before Chapters in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am writing a thesis with latex+biber where I would like to have my own publications listed before the first Chapter, while at the same time I want individual bibliographies for each chapter.
This works so far with refsections, but I also want to be able to cite my own publications in each chapter. My publications have a labelprefix to avoid confusion.

I know that I can nest \newrefsection and \newrefsegment but then my publications will be printed just before \endrefsection after the chapters.

Is there a way to print my publications before the chapters but still cite it? I use individual bib files and I would like to avoid changing anything about the entries like keywords.